# IF ELSE Statement in WHERE Clause SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to achieve the following from sql, Suppose I have `@accountId int` as a parameter in stored procedure, now if I pass parameter as `99999` then in all the select statements it Select `WHERE AccountId <> 124` otherwise if I Pass any other parameter it Selects `WHERE AccountId=@accountId`. This statement is a part of a very long stored procedure, so I haven't Included whole procedure.

```
WHERE (IF(AccountId = 99999) 
       BEGIN
          AccountId <> 124
       END
       ELSE
       BEGIN
          AccountId = @accountId
       END)
```

OR Can I achieve similar from CASE Statement.
Something Like,

```
WHERE (AccountId(CASE(AccountId) WHEN 99999 THEN <>124 ELSE =@accountId))
```

I have edited my question, I apologize for asking it in unrelated manner. Please let me know if it makes sense for you or you need any further information.

Comment: You might want to consider using `NULL` instead of a _magic number_ to indicate that you don't want to filter on `AccountId`: `where ( @AccountId is NULL and AccountId <> 124 ) or ( @AccountId is not NULL and AccountId = @AccountId )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE (AccountId =  1 and  SenderId <> 10) 
   or (AccountId <> 1 and  SenderId =  10) 

WHERE (@AccountId =  9999 and  SenderId <> 10) 
   or (@AccountId <> 9999 and  SenderId =  @AccountId)
```